# DownloadFile creates 0-byte files

Tags: c#, .net

Whenever I use WebClient.DownloadFile(), the resulting file length is always 0 bytes.  I've tried files from different websites including my own IIS locally, always get a 0-byte length file.  When clicking the filename in the browser (Chrome), the file downloads correctly.

```
string fileName = @"us_ysera_tier11.json.gz";
string remoteUri = @"http://wowprogress.com/exports/ranks/" + fileName;

if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        webClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something generally wrong, or can someone point me to a working example?

Comment: If you change the filename into something the site doesn't like, and you run the exact same code, you'll download a 145kb html error file. So the code itself is capable of downloading such information. Try sending the same http headers as chrome (you can see them by running Fiddler or an equivalent tool).

Comment: Thanks, I think you're implying something's going on with a particular site or file or browser.  My problem is the above code results in 0-byte files regardless of where I download from, including my local machine's IIS on Win7x64.  So I'm really trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with DownloadFile in general, just using wowprogress as an example, and Chrome as a non-code demonstration that the file(s) from whatever source are downloadable.  Does normal use of DownloadFile() on all sites require custom http headers?

Comment: might quick fix... remove '@' from your strings

Comment: There are zero things wrong with using an '@'. It interprets the string literally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code downloads a 5K file on my machine. I updated the filename and remoteUri values.

```
string fileName = "us_ysera_tier11.json.gz";
string remoteUri = "http://www.wowprogress.com/export/ranks/" + fileName;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "application/x-gzip";
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
```